# Get next 2 rows and current row if current row flag is True in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am learning sql and facing a issue in the following problem-

I want to get next two rows(if it exists) and the current row if current row flag is True.(only for first true flag)
The table is grouped by id and sorted by price.

the table is like:

| ID | price | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | false |
| 1 | 123 | true |
| 1 | 200 | false |
| 1 | 456 | false |
| 1 | 500 | true |
| 2 | 23 | true |
| 2 | 234 | false |

The output I'm expecting is like:

| ID | A | price | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 | 123 | true |
| 1 | 786 | 200 | false |
| 1 | 567 | 456 | false |
| 2 | 2 | 23 | true |
| 2 | 5 | 234 | false |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you share you best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I am using Teradata dbms

Comment: Where are the values in column A in your output coming from?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a beast, but try something like this (replace `TableName` with your actual table name everywhere):

```
WITH
    ThreeRows AS (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            MetaID
        FROM
            (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) ThreeRows (MetaID)
            JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableName) X 
                ON 1=1 -- all combos
        ),
        
    TableNameWithRowNumbers AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    ID
                ORDER BY
                    Price
            ) AS IDRowNumber
        FROM
            TableName
        ),
        
    TableNameWithTrueRowNumbers AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    ID
                ORDER BY
                    IDRowNumber
            ) AS TrueRowNumber
        FROM
            TableNameWithRowNumbers
        WHERE
            flag = 'TRUE'
        ),
    
    FirstTrue AS (
        SELECT
            ID,
            IDRowNumber AS FirstTrue
        FROM
            TableNameWithTrueRowNumbers
        WHERE
            TrueRowNumber = 1
        ),
    
    NonNullRowsWeNeed AS (
        SELECT
            TableNameWithRowNumbers.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    TableNameWithRowNumbers.ID 
                ORDER BY 
                    TableNameWithRowNumbers.IDRowNumber
                ) AS MetaID
        FROM
            FirstTrue
            LEFT JOIN TableNameWithRowNumbers
                 ON TableNameWithRowNumbers.ID = FirstTrue.ID
                AND TableNameWithRowNumbers.IDRowNumber BETWEEN
                    FirstTrue.FirstTrue AND FirstTrue.FirstTrue+2
        )

SELECT 
    ThreeRows.ID,
    NonNullRowsWeNeed.price,
    NonNullRowsWeNeed.flag
FROM 
    ThreeRows
    LEFT JOIN NonNullRowsWeNeed
        ON ThreeRows.ID = NonNullRowsWeNeed.ID
        AND ThreeRows.MetaID = NonNullRowsWeNeed.MetaID 
ORDER BY 
    ID, 
    ThreeRows.MetaID
;
```

The `ThreeRows` CTE ensures the final result has three rows per ID. The rest of the CTEs figure out the location of the first TRUE flag and do some `JOIN` prep by defining IDs. The final query cobbles it all together.

Comment: in NonNullRowsWeNeed cte you have used TableName.IDRowNumber which dosent exist in my table in the sam cte the syntax LEFT JOIN TableNameWithRowNumbers TableName is wrong right in teradata?

Comment: @Radon2 Try again. Was unaware that Teradata had weird aliasing rules.